# after building static version of qt there is no qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

I built a static version of Qt 5.1.1 msvc. but after building there is no qmake.exe and when I execute "qmake" it's not recognized as a internal or external command.
what is the problem?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164630/qmake-is-not-in-the-directory-after-building-static-qt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way the build would succeed without qmake being built and executed numerous times. It's there. Look in your build's `bin` directory. It won't magically be added to your `PATH`!